# Incorrect output when trying to query in a depth first search implementation for prolog

Tags: prolog, depth-first-search

I just can't seem to get the correct output - I am supposed to get -

```
?- dfs([a], X).
X = [a, f, i] ;
false.
```

But I get -

```
?- dfs([a], X).
X = [a|f] ;
```

```
% Representation of a tree
% choose initial state a
arc(a, b).
arc(a, f).
arc(b, c).
arc(b, d).
arc(b, e).
arc(f, g).
arc(f, i).
arc(i, j).
arc(i, k).

% the goal 
goal(i).

dfs([Node|_], [Node|X]) :-
    goal(X).
dfs([Node|_], [Node|X]) :-
    expands([Node|_], NewNode),
    append([Node|_], NewNode, appendedN),
    dfs(appendedN, X).

% expands(+Path, ?NewNode).
% -- Path: is a list of nodes of the form Path=[Node|Nodes], where
%    Node is the node we want to expand and Nodes is a list
%    of remaining nodes already expanded and containing the root.
% -- NewNode: is a constant representing the node we want to go to,
%    as there is an link to it from where we are currently.
%
expands([Node|_], NewNode):-
    arc(Node, NewNode).
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program matches the first clause, `dfs([Node|_], [Node|X])`, and nothing else, producing `X = [a|i]` .

Here's a working version.

```
% Representation of a tree
% choose initial state a
arc(a, b).
arc(a, f).
arc(b, c).
arc(b, d).
arc(b, e).
arc(f, g).
arc(f, i).
arc(i, j).
arc(i, k).

% the goal
goal(i).

% You can expand a starting symbol S to a list L if G is your goal, S expands
% to G in list L1, and you append the two lists.
dfs([S], L) :-
    goal(G),
    expands(S, G, L1),
    append([S], L1, L).

% X expands to Y in list [Y] if there's a direct arc from X to Y (base case).
expands(X, Y, [Y]) :-
    arc(X, Y).

% X expands to Z in list [Y|L] if there's a direct arc from X to Y and Y
% expands to Z in list L (recursive case).
expands(X, Z, [Y|L]) :-
    arc(X, Y),
    expands(Y, Z, L).
```

In this version, `expands()` produces all of the lists that start with `a`:

```
?- expands(a, X, L).
X = b,
L = [b] ;
X = f,
L = [f] ;
X = c,
L = [b, c] ;
X = d,
L = [b, d] ;
X = e,
L = [b, e] ;
X = g,
L = [f, g] ;
X = i,
L = [f, i] ;
X = j,
L = [f, i, j] ;
X = k,
L = [f, i, k] ;
false.
```

Then `dfs()` confirms that the goal `i` has been reached and adds the start symbol `a` to the head of the list:

```
?- dfs([a], X).
X = [a, f, i] ;
false.
```